# Remote Desktop Services continually stops on Windows Server 2016 VM

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

**Environment:**

We have a Windows Server 2016 Virtual Machine running in Hyper-V and is used as our internet desktop (as our normal desktops run on Server 2012R2 and do not connect to the internet.

We normally have an average of ~100 people logged onto the server and around 50-70 active sessions at any given time.

**Issue:**

With this server we would occasionally have an error show up:
[image: Error]

This would only happen around once every 2 weeks so was really not an issue although recently there was a Windows update (which Windows **will** force on you if your Server is on the internet) and since the update this has been happening every few hours and sometimes even after 30 minutes of me fixing it!

The current solution I have is to log onto the host machine and use the Hyper-V console to login to the server and simply restart the `Remote Desktop Services` service and that normally would solve the issue temporarily. (Sometimes I am actually unable to logon through the Hyper-V console and I need to `Turn Off` the machine and restart.)

I have spent some time googling this, reading similar issues although could not find a workable answer and our system is also different as most people who have this issue have 1-5 people logged on where we average around 100 users.

**Logs:**

I am currently filtering the huge mess that is called `Event Viewer` and will edit with logs of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happen when the winlogon service can’t handle gracefully the user login.

Check list to check:

- GPO that utilize a lot of the server CPU. A good exemple is printer mapping if you don’t use by default the Easy Print driver, as the spooler will take huge chunk of CPU to connect the user.
- Clogged profile; make sure the user profile is not locked up by an antivirus, or roaming profile from a slow share.

After that please check a perfmon and/or the hypervisor statistics to see spike usage, but by experience it was always related to bad GPO that cause the winlogon to block new process

Comment: Thank you, I am doing this now and will see if it helps.